# Como conectar em uma base sql server do centos 6 64 bits

Tags: php, sql-server

Já fiz os seguintes procedimentos:

```
rpm -ivh http://dag.wieers.com/rpm/packages/rpmforge-release/rpmforge-release-0.5.2-2.el6.rf.x86_64.rpm
wget http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi.repo
yum install freetds
yum install freetds-devel
yum update
vim /etc/yum.conf <-- retirei os excludes da configuração do yum para fazer a instalação abaixo
yum install --enablerepo=remi php-mssql
```

Mas continua sem conectar "could not find driver".

Comment: Já tentou isso: http://serverfault.com/questions/387661/install-php-mssql-in-centos-6-2